# Basic HTML Select Not working on Mac for Safari or Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, safari

I want to add drop down option and using MacBook Pro but no matter what I add to my template the select shows nothing. I installed Chrome or Firefox as well to check if the issue is just with Safari but I can't see the drop down there either.

Here is the simple drop down I wanted to display:

```
<label>Begin:</label>
<select name="test">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<label>End:</label>
```

[Here is what I see in browser: Click to show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT2Pv.png)

[When trying to add 'html' tag to main.html in Meteor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miF87.png)

Comment: Inspect Element in browser and check!

Comment: The code looks fine to me... Are you sure you are looking at this code when examining it in the browser?

Comment: @KalpeshSingh: I can see the element in inspect....

Comment: @KobyDouek: Yes I can see the page source in dev tool in inspect and the elements are all there including "select" and "options" but I can't see anything showing.

Comment: Is it an external web page? Something I can look at ?

Comment: I am developing using Meteor ... and have number of packages I don't know if that could cause an issue... I can check with just basic HTML File...

Comment: @KobyDouek: its locally hosted ;(

Comment: Could you update the question to include the entire HTML page ?

Comment: Here is what I do see.. the basic works... I wonder if its to do with the fact that Meteor doesn't have "html" tag doc.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding class 'browser-default' to the select. This is to do with Meteor tempting and not having the "html" value tag within the main.html.

Credits to Brian Kinsella! ROCK!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
}
```